# Docking station/xrandr/multiple monitors, is it possible to combine monitors?

Tags: usb, 22.04, multiple-monitors, display, xrandr

I have connected three monitors to my docking station. Two using display port and one using HDMI. Docking station connects to laptop using USB-C connector. All other inputs such as network, mouse and keyboard are also connected to docking station. Two monitors are set in portrait mode and are my primary work monitors set side by side.

This setup works correctly for normal operations. I've all four monitors working and no issues.

I would like to use two portrait monitors as one combined monitor. Based on research xrandr should be able to do it but does not work in my case. xrandr does see all monitors and is able work with basic commands such as display off, change resolution etc, but not able to join two monitors.

I also came across a screenshot where displays applet has buttons to join/mirror screens I don't get those buttons in the applet.

Is there any way to join the monitors while using docking station? Goal is to combine DP-2-1 and DP-2-2 as one big monitor

Output of xrandr --listmonitors

```
 0: +*eDP-1 1920/344x1080/194+4080+840  eDP-1
 1: +DP-2-3 1920/525x1080/297+0+840  DP-2-3
 2: +DP-2-2 1080/527x1920/296+3000+0  DP-2-2
 3: +DP-2-1 1080/527x1920/296+1920+0  DP-2-1
```

Output of xrandr | grep connected

```
eDP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+4080+840 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2-1 connected 1080x1920+1920+0 left (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 527mm x 296mm
DP-2-2 connected 1080x1920+3000+0 right (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 527mm x 296mm
DP-2-3 connected 1920x1080+0+840 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 525mm x 297mm
```

Ubuntu 22.04, all service packs up to date.